# PHP Simple HTML DOM - Access values that has no identifiers

Tags: php

Say I have this in the html

```
<strong class="top">Contact Person: </strong>
<br>
Shan
<strong class="top">Email-id: </strong>
<br>
<span>abshanai@gmail.com</span>
<br>
<strong class="top">Website:</strong>
www.absgym.co.in
```

is it possible to get the values using simple html DOM?

Comment: what exactly are you going to do ?

Comment: i need to store it in a variable in PHP like $name=$html->find(#id), so for this one how can i use find to access each values

Comment: sorry but I can't understand what do you mean , or what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sourcelink = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model';
$retriever = curl_init(); curl_setopt($retriever, CURLOPT_URL, $sourcelink);
curl_setopt($retriever, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($retriever, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
curl_setopt($retriever, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); curl_setopt($retriever,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); curl_setopt($retriever, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$source_content =curl_exec ($retriever); curl_close ($retriever);

/*
 *preg_match('/The starting of content's html tag(.*?)ending of content's html tag, source, variable with results)
 */

preg_match('/<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" lang="en">(.*?)<div id="bodyContent" class="mw-body-content">/s',$source_content,$selected_area);

$needed_content=$selected_area[0];

$dom_class = new DOMDocument();

@$dom_class->loadHTML($needed_content);

$processor = new DOMXPath($dom_class);

/*
 * This must be the html tag which is enclosing the targetted content to extract, syntax as below,
 * $processor->query('//html tag[@html_attribute="value"]');
 */
$process_selector = $processor->query('//span[@dir="auto"]');

foreach( $process_selector as $valuesalue ) {
    echo $values=trim($valuesalue->nodeValue); echo '<br>';
    $accumaltor[]=$values;
}
```

?>

**Follow:**

1. Mandatory lines to be changed are 3, 15 and 16 from the above code corresponding to your determined DOM document.
2. Line #3: Use your URL
3. Line #15: The HTML parent tags enclosed your determined section of HTML DOM.
4. Line #16: This must be the html tag which is enclosing the targeted content to extract. In your case it is `<strong class="top>Targeted content to extract</strong>`, so

`$process_selector = $processor->query('//strong[@class="top"]');`